# Restrict User Access to Object by Field Value

Tags: security, user, object, access

Is there a way to restrict a user's access to a subset of objects by field value? Essentially I'm trying to create a profile that only has access to orders/accounts/contacts that have a boolean field set to true.

Is there anyway to accomplish this as described? Or how do you segment these types of records so each user can't see everything?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a session based permission set for each one of the object
2. Enable and assign the permission set programatically or use Salesforce Lightning Flows to the user